# Update data based on time expiring in the browser

Tags: jsx

I have a piece of data that I want to update when it expires, this data has a stored value and expiry, both of which are date/time in milliseconds.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this, I'm thinking I need to have the browser keep track of time and when the current time matches the expiry time I can then make a call to update.

I'm not sure if/what the call would be to make the browser aware of this?
The project is React App, I was also considering using socket.io as another option.

edit: want to avoid using setTimeout, as I need to call this on a lifecycle method to check. Ideally, if a user never leaves the page/component, so no new lifecycle methods are triggered, i still want to check and push the update to them.

Answer (score 0):

Will there be a new datapoint once this one is expired?

You could check to see how long the current data is still valid when it get's mounted. Then, set a timeout for that duration which will call the function to get the new datapoint. After that, keep using that logic. Basically, have a variable setTimeout value that is based on the expiration date minus the Date.now().

Comment: calls the same point, however im looking for a way to do this without using setTimeout or checking on willMount, if a user stayed on page and never left, i want to still update. unfortuantly this means the user never goes anywhere so a lifecycle doesnt get kicked off.

Comment: Well, I guess you can setup a socket that pushes a new data point and update the view on that event. Having a static object with an expiration date will require you to do something like a setTimeout. You could even let the backend set timeouts for the data points and emit the event over a socket to all clients that are listening.